# Topology of pointwise convergence on symmetric groups

Tags: general-topology, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

Let $X$ be a countable set, and consider the topology of pointwise convergence of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$, the symmetric group on $X$.

Then one can characterize the closed sets as follows: *an element $g \in \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is in a closed set $C$ if and only if for every finite subset $A \subset X$ there is a $g_A \in C$ for which $g$ and $g_A$ agree on $A$.*

Is there a similar characterization for uncountable $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same characterisation for uncountable $X$. But the pleasant thing about the countable case is that $\text{Sym}(X)$ is completely metrisable, and for uncountable $X$ not first countable nor even normal. So much "uglier".

Comment: what do you mean by "the same" ?

Comment: @Boccherini the same characterisation of closed sets.

Comment: also with only the finiteness condition on the sets A ? Do you have a reference ?

Comment: @Boccherini It's obvious: you give the set the subspace topology it inherits from the product topology on $X^X$ and that's the way the product topology is defined. We put the discrete topology on the set $X$.